# Making a Redux reducer pure when it accesses an external file for its default state

Tags: javascript, redux

I'm creating a Redux reducer to modify my app's configuration. I have config defaults in an external file, and I want to use those as the default state. Because I'm accessing the contents of an external file, which could change, does that make my reducer impure? If so, how can I re-write this to make it pure?

reducer:

```
import configDefaults from './configDefaults';
export default const configOptions = (state = configDefaults, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_GLOBAL_CONFIG_PARAMETER':
        return {...state, [action.parameter]: action.value};
    default:
        return state;
    }
};
```

config file:

```
export default configDefaults = {
    fontSize: 12,
    backgroundColour: 'white'
};
```

Answer (score 1):

> Because I'm accessing the contents of external file, which could change, does that make my reducer impure?

No, it's just the defaultValue, it is used when the `state == undefined`

You could also pass the default state when you are creating the store:

`createStore(appStore, { appConfigs: configDefaults })`

**Pure Function, is a function, which does not have side-effects.**

initialState can be different in each version of the app, like the reducer itself but it's still pure..

Comment: I want to believe you (because that will make my life easier) but just to push the point.... If, at some point in the future, I decide that I want my app configuration to be different, so I change the config file contents, that will change the output of my reducer when I don't define an input state as a parameter. On the one hand, that sounds like an impure reducer. On the other hand, I've also essentially re-written the app, so it could still be considered pure _for that version of the app_. Is the latter interpretation correct, or am I still missing something about how to define pure/impure?

Comment: Here's a further scenario: the app itself changes the content of the configDefaults file. In this scenario, the reducer could produce different outputs from before versus after that file modification, even with the same reducer input parameters. Doesn't that make the reducer impure?

Comment: you are dealing with stuff, that just stops the progress of your app

Comment: I guess, you don't understand the meaning of a pure-function.

Comment: Yes, a pure function is one which does not have side-effects. However, it is not _only_ that. It is also one which, given the same input, always produces the same output. My question boils down to the definition of "input". With the following function... `const f = (a=default) => {...}` `a` is the only parameter for the function and the only value one provides as "input" when you call the function. From that perspective, `f` is impure. However, if you consider both `a` and `default` to be "inputs", then one could consider `f` to be pure. So, yes, I _am_ trying to understand pure functions.

Comment: a default value, is a function setting.. it's like `function(a) { a = a || defaultValue; return a + 1; }`